# Не получаеться вывести в консоль содержимое атрибута элементов

Tags: javascript, html, hover, popup

На сайте есть текст, при наведении на некоторые слова всплывает подсказка в которой текст с объяснением термина, мне нужно вывести текст всех подсказок в консоль и я пользуюсь следующим кодом:

```js
var i = 0;
var s='';
while (i < document.getElementsByClassName("term").length) {
s=s+document.getElementsByClassName('term')[i].innerHTML+'\n'
+document.getElementsByClassName('term')[i].getAttribute('data-original-title')+'\n';
i++;
}
console.log(s);
```

Но он работает только после того как самому пройтись по всем подсказкам и уже после его запустить, в противном случае он везде выводит null

Answer (score 1):

Вытаскиваем значение стандартного атрибута:

```js
let i = 0, s = '', a = [...document.querySelectorAll('.term')];
while (i < a.length) {
  s += `${a[i].innerHTML}\n${a[i].getAttribute('title')}\n`;
  i++;
}
console.log(s);
```

```html
<p class="term" title="Подсказка 1">Термин 1</p>
<p class="term" title="Подсказка 2">Термин 2</p>
```

Пользовательские атрибуты (`data-`) извлекаются немного [иначе](https://learn.javascript.ru/attributes-and-custom-properties#svoystvo-dataset-data-atributy):

```js
let i = 0, s = '', a = [...document.querySelectorAll('.term')];
while (i < a.length) {
  s += `${a[i].innerHTML}\n${a[i].dataset.originalTitle}\n`;
  i++;
}
console.log(s);
```

```html
<p class="term" data-original-title="Подсказка 1">Термин 1</p>
<p class="term" data-original-title="Подсказка 2">Термин 2</p>
```

Если неизвестно в каком из атрибутов:

```js
let i = 0, s = '', a = [...document.querySelectorAll('.term')];
while (i < a.length) {
  s += `${a[i].innerHTML}\n${(a[i].getAttribute('title') || a[i].dataset.originalTitle) || 'Подсказки нэээту. Савсэм!'}\n`;
  i++;
}
console.log(s);
```

```html
<p class="term">Термин 0</p>
<p class="term" title="Подсказка 1">Термин 1</p>
<p class="term" data-original-title="Подсказка 2">Термин 2</p>
<p class="term" title="Подсказка 3" data-original-title>Термин 3</p>
<p class="term" title data-original-title="Подсказка 4">Термин 4</p>
```

Comment: Все так-же выводит undefined (только раньше было NULL), но если курсором сначала пройтись по терминам чтобы отобразилась подсказка - то после в консоле их выводит.

Comment: @Михаил: здесь работает?

Comment: Да, вот картинка с нужного ресурса: https://i.imgur.com/fmvexf5.png
Пока не не наводил курсор на подсказку - не выдавало ее в консоль, а после выдает.

Comment: @Михаил: похоже, что там динамически подгружается текст подсказки.

Comment: Вот сам код - https://i.imgur.com/FEicdE4.png

Comment: @Михаил: посмотрите в инспекторе код блока у которого ещё не всплывала подсказка. Скорее всего, атрибут с подсказкой появляется во время наведения, а после уже остаётся, чтобы повторно не подгружаться.

Comment: До - https://i.imgur.com/Dh6D4Xq.png
После - https://i.imgur.com/YEGguPs.png

Выходит никак нельзя реализовать нужный скрипт :( ?

Comment: @Михаил: подождите... Там же есть подсказка изначально. Но, после наведения, она переносится в data-атрибут. Когда Вам нужно получать список: до наведения, после наведения или в любом случае?

Comment: Мне нужно открыть страницу - вбить в консоль скрипт - получить все подсказки списком, сейчас скрипт их дает только после предварительного "проклацивания" вручную

Comment: @Михаил: ну, вот и получается, что Вам нужно не водить по ссылкам, а делать так, как говорите - открыли-вбили-получили. И получать нужно тогда не `data-original-title`, а просто `title`. Сейчас дополню.

Comment: А я проверял, дает undefined :(

Comment: @Михаил: дополнил. Проверяйте последний вариант. Если не сработает, то что-то там нечисто.

Comment: Чудеса! Оно работает! Но если случайно вручную навестись то подсказку того термина уже не выводит, если не сложно сделать чтобы выводило в любом случае то будет просто идеально, но в любом случае огромное спасибо!

Comment: @Михаил: так я три варианта сделал. Последний должен работать.

Comment: все отлично работает, огромное спасибо! Милиард человеко-часов спасено <3